# Javascript low poly generator with color change

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I fell in love with something that I've found on [wata.pimmey.com](http://wata.pimmey.com), I think the color changing low poly background is just beautiful. I've checked the source code of the page and the scripts attached to it, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Maybe It's because I'm just a noob and didn't see something obvious in there. I'd be really thankful if anyone could help me to find the exact code to make a similar background or even find some third-party tools that could re-create the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

PD: I'm sorry for any grammar errors  that I could have made in this post, english is not my native language. I'll study it a bit more.

EDIT: Nevermind, found it [github.com/msurguy/triangles](https://github.com/msurguy/triangles)

Answer (score 1):

its done using multiple svg shapes and tracking the mouse as the mouse moves around the screen it calculates how to shade the different triangles

if you look closely you can see the changing color values based on mouse position

for the method of calculating the color you will have to use ur imagination or inspect further

have a try at

`getEventListeners(document.getElementByIdName('triangles') )`

[image]

[image]